# DB2 connectivity from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to connect to DB2 from Excel using VBA.
Is there any driver i need to install for this.I am very new to this.So please do help.
PFB the connection string i used

```
DBCONSRT ="Provider=DB2OLEDB;Datasource=hfdvdb2.intra.testdb.com:40001/TESTQA;Hostname=hfdvdb2.intra.testdb.com;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=40001;Uid=testusr;Pwd=testpwd;

Set DBCON = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
DBCON.ConnectionString = DBCONSRT
DBCON.Open
```

Is this the correct way to give the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the DB2 OLEDB Provider for DB2.  See this link.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29100

For example connection strings, the download itself should have documentation.  However, a great site for connection strings is http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has been creating their own OLEDB providers for DB2 (the IBM's downloads are multi-hundred megabytes and behind paywalls).

The drivers are known as **Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2**, and have been released along with the various SQL Server *"Feature Packs"*.

**Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 Version 5.0 HotFix** *- December 15 2015*

- [Release announcement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3104962/an-update-for-the-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-db2-v5-is-now-available)
- [x64 Package](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20OLEDB%20Provider%20for%20DB2%20v5/latest/3104962_x64/9.0.2343.0/free/488932_ENU_x64_zip.exe) (488932_ENU_x64_zip.exe)
- [x86 Package](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20OLEDB%20Provider%20for%20DB2%20v5/latest/3104962_x86/9.0.2343.0/free/488931_ENU_i386_zip.exe) (488931_ENU_i386_zip.exe)

**Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 Version 5.0** *- January 28 2015*

- Available with the [SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)
- [x64 Package](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/3/0/13089488-91FC-4E22-AD68-5BE58BD5C014/ENU/DB2OLEDBV5_x64.msi) (DB2OLEDBV5_x64.msi)
- [x86 Package](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/3/0/13089488-91FC-4E22-AD68-5BE58BD5C014/ENU/DB2OLEDBV5_x86.msi) (DB2OLEDBV5_x64.msi)

**Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 Version 4.0 Refresh** *- December 31 2012*

- [Release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sjackson/2012/12/31/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-db2-v4-0-refresh-is-available/) *([archive](http://archive.is/XpzzC))*
- Available with the [SQL Server 2012 SP1 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)
- [x64 Package](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/B/1/4B1E9B0E-A4F3-4715-B417-31C82302A70A/ENU/x64/DB2OLEDBV4_x64.msi) (DB2OLEDBV4_x64.msi)
- [x86 Package](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/B/1/4B1E9B0E-A4F3-4715-B417-31C82302A70A/ENU/x86/DB2OLEDBV4_x86.msi) (DB2OLEDBV4_x64.msi)

**Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 Version 3.0** *- June 11 2010*

- [Release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sjackson/2010/06/11/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-db2-v3-0-is-available/) *([archive](http://archive.is/s1UrS))*
- Available with the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978)
- [Package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188403&clcid=0x409) (DB2OLEDB.exe)

**Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 Version 2.0** *- September 3 2008*

- [Release announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sjackson/2008/09/03/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-db2-2-0-is-now-available/) *([archive](http://archive.is/B68tL))*
- Available with the SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack
- [Package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123713&clcid=0x409) (DB2OLEDB.exe)

## Microsoft OLEDB Provider for DB2 - Version 5.0 Hotfix

Here's a the KB for the latest (as of 3/15/2017 1:11pm) version of the OLEDB provider.

> ## [An update for the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 v5 is now available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3104962/an-update-for-the-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-db2-v5-is-now-available)
>
> ### Summary
>
> A refreshed version of the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 v5 is now
>   available. This update contains all fixes that are implemented for the
>   Data Integration feature of [Cumulative Update 3 for Microsoft Host
>   Integration Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3019572).
>
> **Important note about the updated package**
>
> This update requires removing the earlier version of the Microsoft OLE
>   DB Provider for DB2 v5.
>
> ### More Information
>
> This update contains the following fixes for Host Integration Server
>   2013:
>
> - All the fixes that were included in [Cumulative update package 3 for Host Integration Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3019572)
> - All the fixes that were included in [Cumulative update package 2 for Host Integration Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2929767)
> - All the fixes that were included in [Cumulative update package 1 for Host Integration Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2908834)
> - All previously released hotfixes for Host Integration Server 2013
>
> ### Hotfix information
>
> A supported hotfix is available from Microsoft Support. However, this
>   hotfix is intended to correct only the problem that is described in
>   this article. Apply this hotfix only to systems that are experiencing
>   the problem described in this article. This hotfix might receive
>   additional testing. Therefore, if you are not severely affected by
>   this problem, we recommend that you wait for the next software update
>   that contains this hotfix.
>
> If the hotfix is available for download, there is a "Hotfix download
>   available" section at the top of this Knowledge Base article. If this
>   section does not appear, contact Microsoft Customer Service and
>   Support to obtain the hotfix.
>
> **Note** If additional issues occur or if any troubleshooting is required, you might have to create a separate service request. The
>   usual support costs will apply to additional support questions and
>   issues that do not qualify for this specific hotfix. For a complete
>   list of Microsoft Customer Service and Support telephone numbers or to
>   create a separate service request, go to the following Microsoft
>   website:
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support
>
> **Note** The "Hotfix download available" form displays the languages for which the hotfix is available. If you do not see your language, it
>   is because a hotfix is not available for that language.
>
> ### Prerequisites
>
> To apply this hotfix, you must first uninstall the existing
>   installation of Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 v5. Then, use the
>   .msi file that is listed in the "File information" section to install
>   this hotfix.
>
> ### Restart information
>
> You may have to restart the computer after you apply this hotfix
>
> ### Replacement information
>
> This hotfix does not replace any previously released hotfix.
>
> ### File information
>
> The English version of this hotfix has the file attributes (or later
>   file attributes) that are listed in the following table. The dates and
>   times for these files are listed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
>   When you view the file information, it is converted to local time. To
>   find the difference between UTC and local time, use the **Time Zone**
>   tab in the **Date and Time** item in Control Panel.
>
> ```
> | File name               | File version   | File size | Date        | Time  | Platform       |
> |-------------------------|----------------|-----------|-------------|-------|----------------| 
> | [Db2oledbv5_x64.msi][7] | Not applicable | 4,210,176 | 13-Oct-2015 | 22:09 | Not applicable | 
> | [Db2oledbv5_x86.msi][8] | Not applicable | 3,083,776 | 13-Oct-2015 | 22:09 | Not applicable |
> ```
>
> ### References
>
> Learn about the [terminology](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/824684) that Microsoft uses to describe
>   software updates.
>
> ### Properties
>
> Article ID: 3104962 - Last Review: Dec 15, 2015 - Revision: 1
>
> Applies to   Microsoft Host Integration Server 2013
>
> ---
>
> KB Article Number(s): 3104962
>   - Language: English
>   - Platform: i386
>   - Location: [488931_ENU_i386_zip.exe](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20OLEDB%20Provider%20for%20DB2%20v5/latest/3104962_x86/9.0.2343.0/free/488931_ENU_i386_zip.exe)
>
> KB Article Number(s): 3104962
>   - Language: English
>   - Platform: x64
>   - Location: [488932_ENU_x64_zip.exe](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Microsoft%20OLEDB%20Provider%20for%20DB2%20v5/latest/3104962_x64/9.0.2343.0/free/488932_ENU_x64_zip.exe)

---